# How to Edit And Delete the Searched Data From JSON WebService Using Android

Tags: android, web-services, edit

I have Searching Data in ListView from WebService Using JSON from Android, but I want to modify and delete that searched data. How to put coding for that? Please help me.

```
//  SEARCHING Data from webservice  and binding in listview  //


private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    DateTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Status = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    JobNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_JobNo);


    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Add_Update_User.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Processing Please Wait ...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        String flag="S" ;
         ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
        params.clear();

             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("JobNo",JobNo.getText().toString()));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("flag",flag));
            //Getting JSON from URL
             JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url,params);
            return json;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        pDialog.dismiss();

         try {
             if (JobNo.getText().toString().equals("") )
            {
                Toast.makeText(Add_Update_User.this, "The Field Should not be null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                 }
             else
             {
                // Getting JSON Array from URL
                    Cargo = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CargoTrack);
                    for(int i = 0; i < Cargo.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = Cargo.getJSONObject(i);



                    String JobNo = c.getString(TAG_JobNo);
                    String Status = c.getString(TAG_Status);
                    String Datetime = c.getString(TAG_DateTime);

                    // Adding value HashMap key => value

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_JobNo, JobNo);
                    map.put(TAG_Status, Status);
                    map.put(TAG_DateTime, Datetime);

                    CargoTracklist.add(map);
                    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                    //SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Add_Update_User.this, CargoTracklist,
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Add_Update_User.this, CargoTracklist,
                            R.layout.listview_row,
                            new String[] { TAG_JobNo,TAG_Status, TAG_DateTime }, new int[] {
                                    R.id.user_JobNo_txt,R.id.user_Status_txt, R.id.user_Date_Time_txt });

                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        SimpleAdapter adapter;
                        @Override
                         public void onClick(View view) {
                            list.setAdapter(null);
                            CargoTracklist.clear();
                            if(adapter != null){
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                           new JSONParse().execute();
                         }
                        }); 


                }
                 }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Connected To Internet",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
    }


     }
}
```

Comment: why you dot google this

Comment: Ya i Searched i didnt get any proper idea...help me

Comment: first of all tell what you have tried, do you store the data which you got from search in local db??

Comment: Actually i created inserting data in sqllite from asp.net Json webservice. and i updated that stored data to server.then i searched that updated data and present in listview . now i want to modifying and deleting that searched data and wants to update again

Comment: do the same as you did early,update the sqlite data with the new data and do the operations locally and update to the server

Comment: ya i used.. but i want searched data to be modified.

Comment: what is the problem in searched data?? you can modify that by updating the db?? is it work/

Comment: no actually am used seperate listview xml. for inserting and searching. .from diff class. so i cant

Comment: there also u can use the same db , and did as u did early

Comment: k thanks u sir lets try

Comment: no its not working.. once i updated data to server ,sqllite data will be deleted . .so i cant . after searching data from server i want to modify .. is it posible or not?

Comment: yes it is possible,there are 2 ways to do that, 1) insert in to db after searching  and modify 2)keep the values in a class of array list and modify there

Comment: i cant you. will you please show sample coding

Comment: no need to sample code after searching data please insert into db again and update

Comment: sir is it posible . list of items in listview have to store in android sqllite . by how?

Comment: from where are you showing item in list view, i mean from where you are showing data from search to list view

Comment: From Local webserver .sir..

Comment: can you please add the code where you are adding the data to list view

Comment: sir i attached code in above

Comment: can you please tell me where you are setting value in the listview from search. Delete the other code

Comment: ok fine you are setting value to test view from `CargoTracklist` is it ?

Comment: then what is the problem, please insert that value to the db and edit as you wanted, you can insert it before you show

Comment: how to use that ...i dont know how to do that ...please sample coding..how to insert searched  into sqlite before adapting in to listview.

Comment: hmm ok try this http://mrbool.com/how-to-insert-data-into-a-sqlite-database-in-android/28895

Comment: there is no possible way to modifying the searched data in listview .and updtae to server directly

Comment: before you display value in the list view you can insert in to the DB as above link, and list view onclick allow you to edit data and save it again in the DB, then update